# invoke another chaincode from one chaincode for getHistoryForKey but return null

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I invoke another chain code from one chain code for `getHistoryForKey` but return null,
my network is

```
peer0.org1  peer0.org3    channel1
peer0.org2  peer0.org3    channel2
```

- the `chaincode1` is installed on `channel1`
- the `chaincode2` is installed on `channel2`

I invoke `chanincode2` installed on `peer0.org3`, and `chaincode2` call the chaincode1 installed on `peer0.org3` , `getHistoryForKey` is used in `chaincode1`. 
However, the response is null

Comment: can you show us some code, so we can better understand what exactly are you trying to do? from your description it's pretty hard to guess what is wrong with what you are trying to achieve.